# chat bot with Named Entity Recognition, NER

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Advice is needed in creating a Telegram bot assistant that will be able to recognize natural language (Russian), analyze it, and, depending on the context, extract entities (currently only dates). The user's text can be very diverse, including handwritten dates and dates in numerical format. I plan to write it in Node.JS. I am aware of the existence of GPT, but for some reasons, I cannot use it. Please share your experience on how to best implement this task, what pitfalls to watch out for, and the complexity of implementation. I have no experience in working with machine learning, neural networks, and NLP.

At the moment, I'm doing a lot of googling and have identified 2 libraries that seem suitable to me. These are TensorFlow and Natural. How well could they fit for solving this task?

Comment: In its current form, this question is too open-ended to receive a good answer here. Questions asking for library recommendations are usually closed as off-topic, and so are those where the answer is expected to be an overview/tutorial for a broad topic like writing a complete application from scratch. Instead, can you edit your question to focus on a specific issue or single implementation detail? What have you tried so far? If you haven't actually started working on your project, I would recommend you find a good tutorial first, and if you get stuck at a specific step, ask about that here

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.